# based on api status vue js array updated

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am new in vue js . I want to call api . it is perfectly working. but i want to put condition on that if api response is this than vue js array is updated .
this is my code . but it gives me error "do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers."
How to handle this?

```
 axios.post(baseUrl+'/api/v1/addProductWishlist',pitem,
                {headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + x,
                'Content-Type':'application/json'
              }
              }).then(r => {
                  if(r.data.status == 202)
                  {
                    
                  }
                  else{
                    state.cartItems.push(payload);

                  }
              });
```

Answer (score 0):

use `Mutation` to modify state, do not redirect change state instance

for more detail: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html

Answer (score 0):

Notice that you don't follow the correct pattern of using Vuex.
You should update the state ONLY from within a mutation. It is an important part in state management in Vuex (as well as in other frameworks). Not following this concept might break the reactivity Vuex maintains and make a big app extremely unpredictable since you can't follow which part of the app have changed a value in your state.

A good practice would be to separate mutations, actions and api calls to 3 different files. The action might be your functionality manager - create an action that calls the api file function (that only executes the axios api call), and after getting back the response calling the mutation from the mutations file to update the state accordingly.

```
// actions.js
{
  myAction: async ({ commit }) => {
    const response = await myApiCall();
    if (response.data.status == 202) { ... }
    else {
      commit('ADD_CART_ITEM', response.item)
    }
  }
}

// api.js
export function myApiCall() {
  return axios.post(...)
}

// mutations.js
{
  ADD_CART_ITEM: (state, payload) => state.cartItems.push(payload);
}
```